# How to put all the numbers that come through "For loop" in one array in PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, input

The problem is that I want all the numbers that come trough the loop to store in an array outside the loop, The HTML code is like this:

```
<div class="col-md-2 px-1 mb-1">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nr" name="var1">
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 px-1 mb-1">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nr" name="var2">
</div> ...
```

And PHP Code is like this:

```
for($i=0; $i<=36; $i++){

    if(isset($_GET["var$i"])){
    $varCheck = $_GET["var$i"];

     echo $varCheck;

    $count++;
    }
    else{
        "";
    }   


}

echo "<h1>".$count."</h1>";
```

Comment: Do you simply want a PHP array with all the values after the loop runs?

Comment: You might simply want to name your inputs something like: `name="var[]"`. This way `$_GET['var']` will yield an array of inputs. No loop needed.

Answer (score 0):

```php
$result = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < 36; $i++) {

    $var = 'var' . $i;

    if (!isset($_GET[$var]) || strlen(trim($_GET[$var])) === 0)
        continue;

    $result[] = $_GET[$var];
}

// array $result ready to use
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can declare an array variable at the top of for loop,

```
$num_arr = []; //empty array
```

inside `if` statement, you can do

```
`array_push($num_arr, $varCheck);` // this will add elements to the array every iteration
```

outside the loop, you can print the array content:

```
`print_r($num_arr);`
```

The `$count++` is unnecessary in this case, unless you really want to count how many iterations.